# How to not allow textbox to have a negative value? (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net

noob question here. I'm trying to write a program so that when someone left clicks on a label, the value in a text box goes up by 1. When they right click on it, the value goes down by 1. It all works, except I don't want the value to ever be able to become a negative number. I tried to stop it from happening, and it works when a positive value is already in the textbox. BUT if you right click the label before you left click it (before any value is in the textbox), it still becomes '-1' and then stops there. Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub Label5_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Label5.MouseClick

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        SawWhetOwl.Text = (Val(SawWhetOwl.Text) + 1).ToString()
        Label5.Text = SawWhetOwl.Text
    ElseIf e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        If SawWhetOwl.Text = CInt(SawWhetOwl.Text < 0) Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            SawWhetOwl.Text = (Val(SawWhetOwl.Text) - 1).ToString()
            Label5.Text = SawWhetOwl.Text
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem, I think, is that the value in the text box is starting off as empty, with no value assigned to it. Therefore when I right click it before a value is given to it, it can't calculate whether or not it's less than 0 and it just gives me -1, I think. I'm pretty confused, sorry if this question is confusing. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You might want to use a NumericUpDown if the value or range is important

Comment: How would I apply that in the code that I posted? I'm an absolute beginner at programming so I really don't know what that is.

Comment: They are in the control toolbox - instead of a textbox (for text) use a `NumericUpDown` to collect a number.  It has Min, Max and Decimal place properties to allow what you want

Comment: Is there another way to do this though? I have a very limited amount of time to finish this (it's a school project) and I don't have time to replace the textboxes and have to change the code in multiple places in order to make them into a different type of control. There has to be a way to do it in the code with the textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to check text is not empty for decreasing the count.

```
Private Sub Label5_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Label5.MouseClick

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        SawWhetOwl.Text = (Val(SawWhetOwl.Text) + 1).ToString()
        Label5.Text = SawWhetOwl.Text
    ElseIf e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        If  String.IsNullOrEmpty(SawWhetOwl.Text) OrElse CInt(SawWhetOwl.Text) <= 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            SawWhetOwl.Text = (Val(SawWhetOwl.Text) - 1).ToString()
            Label5.Text = SawWhetOwl.Text
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: visual studio puts a red line under 'IsNullOrEmpty', says it is not declared??

Comment: Ohh right... it should be String.IsNullOrEmpty. Updated the post.

Comment: It seems like it should work, but when I run it and the right click it crashes and then points to the "If SawWhetOwl.Text = CInt(SawWhetOwl.Text < 0) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(SawWhetOwl.Text) Then" line, and says that "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."

Comment: Updated again. Check now